# How to disable hidden key of wifi network Access Point

Tags: linux, wifi, raspbian, access-point

I am using Raspbian.

The problem arised when I changed my wifi AP's hidden key by inserting the following line in wpa_supplicant.conf

```
scan_ssid=1
```

When I try to view the info of wpa_supplicant file or try to edit it with nano, I just see an empty file.

**How can this value of hidden key be returned to as it was initially?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry, It was a silly mistake. I wasn't using root/admin privileges. So, using sudo did all the work.